# Bloomberg web service call for single field and single instrument taking more than 1 min

Tags: c#, soap, bloomberg

I am making a Bloomberg web service GetData call for the "DEBT_TO_EQUITY_FUNDAMENTALS_TKR" field.  I am setting secmaster = true and asking for a single instrument with a CUSIP identifier (with yellowkey = MarketSector.Corp).

This strikes me as a fairly lightweight call having seen people asking for thousands of instruments and dozens of fields at once.

I have played around with setting lots of different settings but I just can't get this request to return in a few seconds.  It gives me the correct return value but it takes longer than 60 seconds.

Any idea if it is possible to get such a request to execute and return in a few seconds?

Thanks

EDIT - Here is the code I am running:

```
public string GetFundamentalTicker(string identifier, InstrumentType identifierType = InstrumentType.CUSIP)
        {
            PerSecurityWS ps = new PerSecurityWS();
            try
            {


                log.DebugFormat("Cert path is: {0}", CertPath);                
                X509Certificate2 clientCert = new X509Certificate2(CertPath, "<password_redacted>");

                ps.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.ErrorFormat("Error in cert setup - {0} - {1}", e.Message, e.InnerException == null ? "" : e.InnerException.Message);
                return null;
            }
            //Set request header
            GetDataHeaders getDataHeaders = new GetDataHeaders();
            getDataHeaders.secmaster = true;
            getDataHeaders.secmasterSpecified = true;
            //getDataHeaders.fundamentals = true;
            //getDataHeaders.fundamentalsSpecified = true;
            //getDataHeaders.programflag = ProgramFlag.oneshot;//unnecessary - defaults to this anyway
            //getDataHeaders.programflagSpecified = true;
            //getDataHeaders.pricing = true;
            getDataHeaders.secid = identifierType;
            getDataHeaders.secidSpecified = true;                    

            SubmitGetDataRequest sbmtGtDtreq = new SubmitGetDataRequest();
            sbmtGtDtreq.headers = getDataHeaders;

            sbmtGtDtreq.fields = new string[] { 
                                                "DEBT_TO_EQUITY_FUNDAMENTALS_TKR"                                                
            };

            int currentFundYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

            //var fundYears = new List<int>();



            List<Instrument> fundYearInstruments = new List<Instrument>();

            Instrument fundYearInstrument = null;

            fundYearInstrument = new Instrument();
            fundYearInstrument.id = identifier;
            fundYearInstrument.typeSpecified = true;
            fundYearInstrument.type = identifierType;

            fundYearInstrument.yellowkey = MarketSector.Corp;
            fundYearInstrument.yellowkeySpecified = true;
            //fundYearInstrument.overrides = new Override[] {};//{ new Override() { field = "EQY_FUND_YEAR", value = currentFundYear.ToString() } };
            fundYearInstruments.Add(fundYearInstrument);
            //fundYears.Add(-1);



            Instrument[] instr = fundYearInstruments.ToArray();
            Instruments instrs = new Instruments();
            instrs.instrument = instr;

            sbmtGtDtreq.instruments = instrs;



            try
            {


                SubmitGetDataResponse sbmtGtDtResp = ps.submitGetDataRequest(sbmtGtDtreq);                       


                RetrieveGetDataRequest rtrvGtDrReq = new RetrieveGetDataRequest();
                rtrvGtDrReq.responseId = sbmtGtDtResp.responseId;

                RetrieveGetDataResponse rtrvGtDrResp;

                do
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(POLL_INTERVAL);
                    rtrvGtDrResp = ps.retrieveGetDataResponse(rtrvGtDrReq);
                }
                while (rtrvGtDrResp.statusCode.code == DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE);                       



                if (rtrvGtDrResp.statusCode.code == SUCCESS)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < rtrvGtDrResp.instrumentDatas.Length; i++)
                    {

                        for (int j = 0; j < rtrvGtDrResp.instrumentDatas[i].data.Length; j++)
                        {

                            if (rtrvGtDrResp.instrumentDatas[i].data[j].value == "N.A." || rtrvGtDrResp.instrumentDatas[i].data[j].value == "N.S." || rtrvGtDrResp.instrumentDatas[i].data[j].value == "N.D.")
                                rtrvGtDrResp.instrumentDatas[i].data[j].value = null;

                            return rtrvGtDrResp.instrumentDatas[i].data[j].value;

                        }


                    }
                    return null;
                }
                else if (rtrvGtDrResp.statusCode.code == REQUEST_ERROR)
                {
                    log.ErrorFormat("Error in the submitted request: {0}", rtrvGtDrResp.statusCode.description);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.ErrorFormat("Error in GetData - {0} - {1}", e.Message, e.InnerException == null ? "" : e.InnerException.Message);
                return null;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Poll interval is 5 seconds and the SOAP web service url is:
https://software.bloomberg.com/datalicensewp/dlws.wsdl

Comment: How do you call the web service? Can you show some code or a URL you are using?

Comment: @assylias I edited my question to contain some code that demonstrates how I call the API.  Thanks

Comment: I have added soap and c# tags to your question (if it's not c# amend as required). The question is not so much a bloomberg question as it is a webservice question.

Comment: Assylias - I appreciate your help and comments.  However, the question really has nothing to do with SOAP.  SOAP is indeed a bloated protocol and can be slow for that reason.  But in my case, the slowness is not due to transport or underlying protocol, it is bloomberg taking a while.  I read in the manual that setting different headers and properties in the bloomberg web service api can change the order of lookup in their databases and can change the total time it takes the request.  So, I am kind of looking for that kind of nuance/advice.  Thank you

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Comment: Yeah - I will create a help desk ticket with bloomberg - that was going to be my next step.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I found out that there is a difference between making the same call to Bloomberg API from, for example, console app (works very fast) and web service (takes a lot of time to start session). And the difference is that console app runs under the same user as bbcomm process, whereas web service (or actually iis process) runs under System account. You can try to log out all users on the PC where web service is hosted and then try to make the call. In this case, I guess, bbcomm goes under System account as no one else is logged in and works fast. It worked for me and the call was answered instantly.