# Wrapper for Bloomberg Data License Web Services

Tags: soap, bloomberg

I'm looking now in [Bloomberg Data License Web Services](http://www.bloomberg.com/enterprise/content/uploads/sites/2/2013/09/Data_License_Brochure.pdf). Note, that this is different from Bloomberg API ( Session/Service/Request, b-pipe, etc ). It is SOAP-based solution to retrieve reference data from Bloomberg DBs. I created a test application just to quickly evaluate this solution:

```
    var client = new PerSecurityWSClient("PerSecurityWSPort"); 
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("{path-to-certificate}", "{password}");
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "";
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "";

var companyFields = new string[] { "ID_BB_COMPANY", "ID_BB_ULTIMATE_PARENT_CO_NAME" , /* ... all other fields I'm interested in */ };
var getCompanyRequest = new SubmitGetCompanyRequest {
    headers = new GetCompanyHeaders { creditrisk = true },
    instruments = new Instruments {
            instrument = new Instrument[] { 
                new Instrument { id = "AAPL US", yellowkey = MarketSector.Equity, yellowkeySpecified = true },
                new Instrument { id = "PRVT US", yellowkey = MarketSector.Equity, yellowkeySpecified = true }
            }
    },
    fields = companyFields
};
var response = client.submitGetCompanyRequest(getCompanyRequest);
if(response.statusCode.code != SUCCESS) {
    System.Console.Error.WriteLine("Response status is " + response.statusCode);
    return;
}
var retrieve = new RetrieveGetCompanyRequest { responseId = response.responseId };
RetrieveGetCompanyResponse getCompanyResponse = null;
do {
    System.Console.Write("*");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    getCompanyResponse = client.retrieveGetCompanyResponse(retrieve);
} while (getCompanyResponse.statusCode.code == DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE);

if (getCompanyResponse.statusCode.code != SUCCESS) {
    System.Console.Error.WriteLine("Response status is " + response.statusCode);
    return;
}

System.Console.WriteLine();
foreach (var instrumentData in getCompanyResponse.instrumentDatas) {
    Console.WriteLine("Data for: " + instrumentData.instrument.id + " [" + instrumentData.instrument.yellowkey + "]");
    int fieldIndex = 0;
    foreach (var dataEntry in instrumentData.data) {
        if (dataEntry.isArray) {
            Console.WriteLine(companyFields[fieldIndex] + ":");
            foreach(var arrayEntry in dataEntry.bulkarray) {
                foreach(var arrayEntryData in arrayEntry.data) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + arrayEntryData.value);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine(companyFields[fieldIndex] + ": " + dataEntry.value);
        }

        ++fieldIndex;
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine("-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --");
}
```

The code looks somewhat bloated (well, it is indeed, SOAP-based in 2015). Hence is my question -- I assume there should be some wrappers, helpers, anything else to facilitate reference data retrieval, [but even on SO there is only one question regarding BB DLWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011747/bloomberg-web-service-call-for-single-field-and-single-instrument-taking-more-th). Is here anyone using DLWS? Are there any known libraries around BB DLWS? Is it *supposed* to be that slow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting into this myself. There are two options for requesting data: SFTP and Web Services. To my understanding, the SFTP option requires a Bloomberg application ("Request Builder") in order to retrieve data.

The second option (Web Services) doesn't seem well-documented, at least for those working with R (like myself). So, I doubt a library exists for Web Services at this point. Bloomberg provides an authentication certificate in order to gain access to their network, as well as their web services host and port information. Now, in terms of using this information to connect and download data, that is still beyond me.

If you or anyone else has been able to successfully connect and extract data using Bloomberg Web Services and R, please post the detailed code to this Blog!

Comment: Joe, 
   Bloomberg will shut down Web Services access, only SFTP will be available. It's not _that_ bad, as you don't need to write all this boilerplate code to keep track of connections, requests, etc. Even though there are some tricks in getting data via SFTP (say, you request "every day at 23:00, but a file can appear at 23:05, then an update at 23:10)
   Regarding Request builder - it is possible to create your own "request files", this is basically about serializing/deserializing from/to .csv-like. Same-ish boiler-plate code.

Comment: I am just about to try their Web Services, though via Node.js (using node-soap, working with JSON instead of XML).

I am wondering, did you get this to work eventually?

Comment: @rezdm It's mid-2017 and Web Services access still exists. Do you have any authoritative information on its longevity? We need to interact with it and I don't want to build a new client (in Ruby) if it's going away.

Comment: @MarkThomas, not sure, as we switched to sftp anyway.

Comment: DLWS is still going strong and used in new development in 2022. I doubt it will disappear this decade. You don't actually need Bloomberg Data License Request Builder to make SFTP work; it facilitates configuration of the SFTP file you submit to request/schedule data, but you can do it all in text config and CLI if need be (except for some advanced features like selecting your security list from a database).